# Make column unique in install schema script

Tags: magento2, install-script, column, upgradeschema

I want my column to be `unique`. It is not an EAV attribute. I have seen some tutorials, where indexes are unique, but I am not sure it is not the same, as making column unique (or am I wrong?). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `addIndex` method having type `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE`, like:

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable(Helper::CONNECTOR_CHANNELS_STANDARD_TABLE)
    )->addColumn(
        'entity_id',
        Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'Id'
    )->addColumn(
        'name',
        Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        [],
        'Channel Name'
    )->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName(
            Helper::CONNECTOR_CHANNELS_STANDARD_TABLE,
            ['name'],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        ),
        'name',
        ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
    )->setComment(
        'Connector Channels'
    );
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

`Helper::CONNECTOR_CHANNELS_STANDARD_TABLE` is table name (string).

#### Update:

If you adding the index manually by a table name you should pass the Index Type as a string (fourth argument):

```
    $setup->getConnection()->addIndex(
        $setup->getTable('my_table'),
        $setup->getIdxName(
            Helper::CONNECTOR_PRIVATE_DATA_TABLE,
            ['protect_code'],
            AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        ),
        'protect_code',
        AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
    );
```

For more info see:

```
\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::addIndex(
    $tableName,
    $indexName,
    $fields,
    $indexType = AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX,
    $schemaName = null
)
```

and

```
\Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::addIndex($indexName, $fields, $options = [])
```

Comment: I got an error ` Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\OpenServer\domains\midwest.loc\vendor\magento\framewor
  k\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 2563`. The last parameter of addIndex method should be just \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE, without array

Comment: @KateSuykovskaya Thanks for discovering the error, I have changed the code

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I haven't found any way to do it in 'magento way', so ugly solution is just: `$setup->getConnection()->query("ALTER TABLE " . $tableName .  " ADD UNIQUE (" . $uniqueColumnName . ");");`